# How can I output a command to a file, without getting a blank file on error?

Tags: linux, command-line, output, error-handling, write

I'm trying to run a command, write that to a file, and then I'm using that file for something else.

The gist of what I need is:

```
myAPICommand.exe parameters > myFile.txt
```

The problem is that `myAPICommand.exe` fails a lot. I attempt to fix some of the problems and rerun, but I get hit with "cannot overwrite existing file". I have to run a separate `rm` command to cleanup the blank `myFile.txt` and then rerun `myAPICommand.exe`.

It's not the most egregious problem, but it is annoying.

#### How can I avoid writing a blank file when my base command fails?

Comment: How is failure indicated? A return code? An empty file?

Comment: @JeffSchaller error is written to the command line, in this case.

Comment: "command-line" meaning redirected to myFile.txt as "stdout", or to the screen in this case, as "stderr"?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I'm sorry. stderr

Comment: Sorry, but you're having it completely backwards; you should redirect the output to a temporary file, and rename the temp file to the final destination *if* your command *succeeds*. `t=$(mktemp); trap 'rm -f "$t"' EXIT INT TERM; the_cmd >"$t" && mv "$t" the_file`. That way, the output file will always contain valid data irrespective on whether the command succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must have "noclobber" set, check the following example:

```
$ echo 1 > 1  # create file
$ cat 1
1
$ echo 2 > 1  # overwrite file
$ cat 1
2
$ set -o noclobber
$ echo 3 > 1  # file is now protected from accidental overwrite
bash: 1: cannot overwrite existing file
$ cat 1
2
$ echo 3 >| 1  # temporary allow overwrite
$ cat 1
3
$ echo 4 > 1
bash: 1: cannot overwrite existing file
$ cat 1
3
$ set +o noclobber
$ echo 4 > 1
$ cat 1
4
```

"noclobber" is only for overwrite, you can still append though:

```
$ echo 4 > 1
bash: 1: cannot overwrite existing file
$ echo 4 >> 1
```

To check if you have that flag set you can type `echo $-` and see if you have `C` flag set (or `set -o |grep clobber`).

## Q: How can I avoid writing a blank file when my base command fails?

Any requirements? You could just simply store the output in a variable and then check if it is empty. Check the following example (note that the way you check the variable needs fine adjusting to your needs, in the example I didn't quote it or use anything like `${cmd_output+x}` which checks if variable is set, to avoid writing a file containing whitespaces only.

```
$ cmd_output=$(echo)
$ test $cmd_output && echo yes || echo no
no
$ cmd_output=$(echo -e '\n\n\n')
$ test $cmd_output && echo yes || echo no
no
$ cmd_output=$(echo -e ' ')
$ test $cmd_output && echo yes || echo no
no
$ cmd_output=$(echo -e 'something')
$ test $cmd_output && echo yes || echo no
yes

$ cmd_output=$(myAPICommand.exe parameters)
$ test $cmd_output && echo "$cmd_output" > myFile.txt
```

Example without using a single variable holding the whole output:

```
log() { while read data; do echo "$data" >> myFile.txt; done; }
myAPICommand.exe parameters |log
```

Comment: I like this answer and will likely accept it eventually. While it fixes my problem, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I have updated my answer if that helps.

Comment: lovely. Thank you. I didn't think of shortcircuit logic.

Comment: I think you need to quote `$cmd_output` otherwise you get unexpected results if `$cmd_output` is (say) `1 == 2`. If you want to protect against "$cmd_output" being only whitespace, I would consider piping it into `grep -q` with a suitable pattern.

Comment: I agree that it isn't bulletproof example @BenMillwood it just suppose to give an idea. With more requirements (different shells handle variables a bit differently, etc.) we could make it better :)

Comment: Storing the output in a variable could become a problem if the output is large.

Comment: @kasperd there are planty of other ways - all depends on the requirements. For example pipe output to a function that will read the output by line and save it to a file or does nothing otherwise, `log() { while read data; do echo "$data" >> myFile.txt; done; } ; myAPICommand.exe parameters |log`. You can as well look for some dedicated to logging packages or even use systemd logging :)

Answer (score 11):

You can delete the file after running, if the command fails, with

```
myAPICommand parameters > myFile.txt || rm myFile.txt
```

But I would suggest clobbering the file instead:

```
myAPICommand parameters >| myFile.txt
```

See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440) for details.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a script to run the myAPICommand.exe, but have it first remove the myFile.txt if it exists. Then you don't have to constantly do the rm command to clean up.

Like:

```
if [ -e myFile.txt ]
then
    rm myFile.txt && myAPICommand.exe
else
```

You could also make it so that your command cleans up after itself. If the file is empty adding something like the following.

Like:

```
if [ -s myFile.txt ]
then
        EXIT 0
else
        rm myFile.txt && EXIT 1
fi
```

Comment: Or just `rm -f` it, which won't complain if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: True.. @BenMillwood